# Implement a circuit as a matrix in ProjectQ

Tags: circuit-construction, projectq

Suppose a have a circuit coded up in ProjectQ, suppose also it is that large to be hard enough to write it down as a unitary matrix by hands (e.g. order-finding, which is rather standard, but turns out to be very complex when you decompose the modular exponent into elementary 1- and 2-qubit gates, the typical Hilbert space size even for simple numbers would be $2^8-2^{10}$).

Can you propose or you maybe you already know an existing way how to obtain a unitary or even a product of unitaries that delivers the circuit results applied to initial state?

Comment: For large circuits such as the one used in period finding, it is a bad idea to try to work with unitary matrices directly. The matrices are just too large. That's why ProjectQ has concepts like [`BasicMathGate`](https://github.com/ProjectQ-Framework/ProjectQ/blob/4674e11baa58e08e1544bd8ac606dde1479802a4/projectq/ops/_basics.py#L488) to specify a gate in terms of a state permutation defined by a lambda. E.g. that's how [MultiplyByConstantModN is implemented](https://github.com/ProjectQ-Framework/ProjectQ/blob/e041ac7aac5225f339211d848d12b407e0f29f99/projectq/libs/math/_gates.py#L152).